# Javascript To PHP Source Code Conversion

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to convert the following client side javascript code to server side PHP in order to protect some code. Below is a sample code of what I would like to have in PHP (and not using `echo` on each line, as this does not hide anything apart from the opening and closing PHP tags!)

```
function calc() {
    var aa = document.a.lsofa.value * 40.77;
    var bb = document.a.ssofa.value * 29.26;
    var z90 = "Text here.";
    var ctt = aa + bb;
    ctt = parseInt(ctt);
    tot = ctt;
    if (tot < 1) {
        var rslt = "Please enter relevant quantities in the form above.";
    }
    else {
        var rslt = "Complete.  We would require " + ctt.toString() + z95 + "";
    }

    document.a.answer.value = rslt
```

Also the `onclick` event of the form would need to be changed (I would like to keep the converted code on the same page an just call this function on form submit).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this:

```
header('Content-type: application/json'); 

$aa  = $_GET["lsofa"] * 40.77;
$bb  = $_GET["ssofa"] * 29.26;
$z90 = "Text here.";
$ctt = aa+bb;
$ctt = intval(ctt);
$tot = $ctt; // not useful

if ($tot<1) {
  echo json_encode(array('result' => "Please enter relevant quantities in the form above."));
} else {
  echo json_encode(array('result' => "Complete.  We would require " . $ctt . $z95));
}
```

called with

```
 $(function() {
   $("#myForm").on("submit",function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
     $.get("calc.php",$(this).serialize(),function(data) {
       alert(data.result);
     });
   });  
 });
```

Comment: Thank you mplungjan, just what the doc ordered!

Comment: You should really use the proper JSON content type header and not build the JSON result as a string, i.e. `header('Content-type: application/json'); echo json_encode(array('result' => 'Please enter relevant quantities in the form above'));`

Comment: @mplungjan I've submitted an edit to your code that fixes a string concat issue.